# Appcelerator Mobile Module Project shows Missing required Android Add-Ons?

Tags: module, appcelerator

I am trying to create a new mobile module project and when I select deployment targets to android it shows an error of Missing required Android Add-Ons [addon.+google.+apis.+[10]]

However, in android sdk manager API 10 were already installed.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like the error message doesn't cause anything. I managed to create the project ignoring the error and no problem in compile/publish the module.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to install SDK for at least API level 21, or better 23 since current target SDK level is 26 since 1st of August 2018 (https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk)

I had similar issue some time ago, so I just reinstalled Android sdk to different location and change path in Appcelerator Studio.

Hope it helps!